# invalid ALTER TABLE option when trying to add fk

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLE OtherCharges
(
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (BookingID) REFERENCES Bookings(BookingID)
);
```

Above is the code I have and the error I am getting is "invalid ALTER TABLE option" any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: What @GordonLinoff is referring to are the outer most parentheses.

Comment: Pretty much any interface (Toad, SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer) shows you EXACTLY where the error was encountered. Use that kind of information in your troubleshooting!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [the SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm). To add a foreign key you'd use

```
ALTER TABLE OTHERCHARGES
  ADD CONSTRAINT OTHERCHARGES_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (BOOKING_ID) REFERENCES BOOKINGS(BOOKING_ID)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Always a good idea to name your constraints something reasonable but simple. Also, for FK's always specify an ON DELETE action, even if it's NO ACTION - that way it's explicitly stated and easy to understand.